# Is there any way I can resume running by clicking the start button?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm new to Python.
I have three buttons in the code:
*the first one* is to start running the chart, *the second one* is to stop running. But, I don't know what I should do if I want to resume running when I press the <kbd>start</kbd> button again.
Once I press <kbd>start</kbd> button, none of the buttons work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter

running=True
def btn1():
    plt.clf()
    while running==True:       
        x=np.arange(1,51)
        f=np.random.choice(x,15,replace=True, p=None)
        x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(f)]
        plt.bar(x_pos, f, color='green')
        print(f)
        plt.xticks(x_pos, x)
        plt.plot()
        plt.pause(0.5)
    plt.ioff()
    plt.show()

def stop():

    global running
    running = False
    

def closewindow():
     window.destroy()
    

window = tkinter.Tk()
screensize = 500, 500
size = str(screensize[0])+'x'+str(screensize[1])
window.geometry(size)

but1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="start", command=btn1).grid(column = 1, row = 1)
but2=tkinter.Button(window, text="end", command=stop).grid(column = 1, row =2)
ext = tkinter.Button(window, text="exit", command=closewindow).grid(column = 1, row =3 )
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you need to set the matplotlib backend to `TkAgg`: `import matplotlib`, then `matploblib.use('TkAgg')`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `while running == True` inside `btn1()`, the other buttons wouldn't work as the program execution will be stuck inside the loop. You'll need to create a thread for this, that executes your `start` action, so that the other buttons (and consequently the remainder of your program) continue executing properly.

Comment: thank you for the help :D, i tried what you have told me to modify the codes but it reacts the same@@

Comment: Once you press start, none of the buttons work. Add that to the question as well

Comment: You need to add `global running` at the beginning of `btn1()`.

Comment: @acw1668 that's not the main issue. Updated the answer

Comment: According to [matplotlib faq](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/faq/howto_faq.html#working-with-threads), `matplotlib` is not thread-safe.